# How to determine what macport (if any) containing an specific file?

Tags: macports

For some reason looking for an [macport](https://www.macports.org) package what containing an specific file, in this case looking for the file:

```
sapi/embed/php_embed.h (probably should be somewhere in the `/opt/local/include/...`)
```

and some php package should contains it.

I have installed the `php55` macport but it doesn't contains the above file.

Unfortunately the `port contents portname` show only the content of already installed packages.

Is possible to show (or find somewhere) what files containing some macport packages without installing them - e.g. how to find what package i need to install to get the `sapi/embed/php_embed.h` file?

Comment: Please check the answer at [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456982/find-a-macports-package-given-a-file-name)

Comment: debian [content search](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages.en.html#search_contents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456982/find-a-macports-package-given-a-file-name):

> Unfortunately MacPorts currently (2.3.1) only supports that if you have the port installed, i.e. if you want to find out which port installed a file on your system. In this case, you can use port provides .

The answer also suggests to use a Linux distribution (e.g. Debian) to search for the file and choose a similar Macports port with the found Debian package name:

Here is a search engine for Debian: [search package content](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages.en.html#search_contents)

Example:
Result for ".../sapi/embed/php_embed.h":

```
File                                        Packages
/usr/include/php5/sapi/embed/php_embed.h    php5-dev
```

Comment: Accepting this, unfortunately macports hasn't php-dev and searching an particular file is painful. Macports is great, but terribly sucks sometimes... ;(